# Publish Google Sheet Add-on with REST Web Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I want to have an add-on for Google Sheet which will give us a URL that we can use to push data into Google Sheet which isn't shared with us. Basically from a Java Project, we wish to push data into the users sheet who installed this add-on, but don't want the users to share the Google Sheet with us due to privacy reasons.

How can we achieve this in Google Apps Script (Published Add-ons) without any human intervention i.e. automatic via marketplace installation? Please guide.

Comment: The add-on would need to create a new apps script file and save it to the persons Google Drive.  That is possible.  The new apps script file should probably have a `doPost()` function in it, to be able to run from a POST request being made to the published URL. and then the user would need to publish the apps script file.  The person installing the add-on may still need to manually publish the apps script file, unless there is a way to use the new Apps Script API to publish it.  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/)  It is possible to create a deployement

Comment: with the new Apps Script API.  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-deployments)  But I'm not sure if that is allowed through an add-on or just within a domain.  In any case, your question is very general, and is therefore "Off Topic" to Stack Overflow.